# How to know if a process is currently used by a user

Tags: python, windows, process, psutil

I am trying to find out if notepad is being used by a user to type in some info or not.
The notepad might be running but i only want the info when it is being used by someone to type some information.

I tried using psutil and it gives me info's like pid's, name, status and started.

Is there a way to get more info about a process or to find if a process is being currently used.

Comment: What is "currently used"? When I typed something in the last minute? The last 10 seconds? 50 ms? When I'm reading the displayed text and not touching the keyboard at all?

Comment: like user is typing in real time basically

Comment: "Real time" is not well defined, so you have to define it yourself (time between single keystrokes is huuuge from a computer's view). That's my whole point.  And I doubt any application will provide data that will suit your definition.

Comment: You can use **GetForegroundWindow** (via pywin32) to check whether Notepad is the active window or not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.